# Is it possible to generate fingerprint using javascript at a device level and not browser level?

Tags: javascript, browser, fingerprint, fingerprintjs

I tried [fingerprintJS](https://fingerprintjs.com/), but that generates fingerprint at a browser level. I was wondering if we can uniquely identify a device, something like generating a fingerprint from chrome, firefox, or any browser on a device that should give the same value.

Comment: Is it possible? Probably, sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create a fingerprint of the browser or device using different libraries. Do note that protections against fingerprinting are becoming more popular across browsers, so their use may not be of great importance in the future.

See: https://blog.jscrambler.com/introduction-to-device-fingerprinting/ for an explanation and some simple JS.

Also the library used: https://github.com/jackspirou/clientjs

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had read this article and tried this approach before, it gives me diffrent fingerprints when I try from different browsers, I need fingerprint at a device level, not browser

Comment: The ClientJS library has an entire section on how to do device fingerprinting. Remember that many browsers and operating systems actively try to prevent fingerprinting, so that may be why you are not seeing matches.

https://clientjs.org/#Device